# How to scramble URL in IIS seamlessly irrespective of the application hosted

Tags: .net, url, iis

I want that the URL displayed in the Browser should be scrambled for the user (So they cannot just change a number/string to try to get access to another record in website).

I wanted to do this URL scrambling using IIS transparently and not the hosted application.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a table in your database that maps each number/string url combination you need to protect to a GUID.
2. Use the new GUID values for your URLs.

Alternatively:

1. Build a default route on your site that will base-64 decode anything after the route address, and redirect to the decoded relative URL (if and only if it matches an actual route... otherwise you have a security problem).
2. Update all the links on your site to use this new route and base-64 encode the relative link addresses.

But you're deceiving yourself if you think you gain any real security that way.

Note that both of these options require changes to your application code. There is *nothing* built into any web server platform to do this for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the very good insight. I was expecting that I won't have to change the application code and somehow I could do this in the Web Server itself (Either thru some add in or some other way).